# Change Opacity of Image Submit Button On Submit

Tags: jquery, forms, opacity

I have a form with the name parameter `name="checkout_confirmation"`, and a submit button with `input type="image" class="confirm_opacity"`.

When the user clicks this submit button, I want for the CSS opacity of the button to change:

```
$('form'namehere input[submit]').css(opacity: .2)
```

or

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
   $(".confirm_opacity").css({"opacity": ".2"});
});
```

These don't work, though. Why?

Comment: could you be more specific about what's not working? just not doing your thing? any errors thrown?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check to include Jquery

```
$('form[name="checkout_confirmation"]').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find(".confirm_opacity").css({"opacity": ".2"});
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ktd9gbu9/6/)

and about your code you said *a submit button with input*  so you need to change input to button

```
$("button[type=submit]").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find(".confirm_opacity").css({"opacity": ".2"});
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ktd9gbu9/7/)

if you want to get the effect then let form submit

```
$('form[name="checkout_confirmation"]').on('submit',function(e){
       var ThisIt = $(this);
       e.preventDefault();
       ThisIt.find(".confirm_opacity").animate({"opacity": ".2"}, 5000 , function(){
       window.location.href = window.location.href + ThisIt.attr('action');
       });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works!  I just had to put this code at the end of my file in the footer and not at the top.  One problem though is now it doesn't go to my action page, is the prevent default thing stopping that?  Thank you!

Comment: @user1741853 yes e.preventDefault() prevent form to reloading the page  .. if you remove this line your page will refresh and you will not get the effect .. so I will update my answer to reload page after effect

Comment: @user1741853 updated answer and tell me what will happen

Comment: @user1741853 glad it helped .. Good Luck :)